# Compare multiple elements in an object against multiple elements in another object of a different array

Tags: powershell, import-csv, foreach-object

Say [hypothetically], I have two .CSVs I'm comparing to try and see which of my current members are original members... I wrote a nested ForEach-Object comparing every $name and $memberNumber from each object against every other object. It works fine, but is taking way to long, especially since each CSV has 10s of thousands of objects. Is there another way I should approach this?

Original_Members.csv

Name,       Member_Number

Alice,      1234

Jim ,       4567

Current_Members.csv

Alice,     4599

Jim,        4567

```
$currentMembers = import-csv $home\Desktop\current_members.csv |

ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name      
    $memNum = $_."Member Number"

    $ogMembers = import-csv $home\Desktop\original_members.csv" |
        ForEach-Object {
            If ($ogMembers.Name -eq $name -and $ogMembers."Member Number" -eq $memNum) {
                $ogMember = "Yes"
            }  
            Else {
                $ogMember = "No"
            }
        }
            [pscustomobject]@{
            "Name"=$name
            "Member Number"=$memNum
            "Original Member?"=$ogMember
            }
} |

select "Name","Member Number","Original Member?" |
Export-CSV "$home\Desktop\OG_Compare_$(get-date -uformat "%d%b%Y").csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Show your nested foreach code

Comment: convert the larger one to a hashtable & then use it as a lookup table. the key can be either the `.Name` or both properties as a string if you need that. ///// you also may want to look at using a hashset.

Comment: Both of them have different (additional) columns. I there a way to only include certain columns in the hashtable/array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both of your files are like the below:

`Original_Members.csv`

```
Name, Member_Number
Alice, 1234
Jim, 4567
```

`Current_Members.csv`

```
Name, Member_Number
Alice, 4599
Jim, 4567
```

You could store the original member names in a [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) for constant time lookups, instead of doing a linear search for each name. We can use [`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netcore-3.1) to create a hashset of `string[]` names.

We can then use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) to filter current names by checking if the hashset contains the original name with [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1), which is an O(1) method.

```
$originalMembers = Import-Csv -Path .\Original_Members.csv
$currentMembers = Import-Csv -Path .\Current_Members.csv

$originalMembersLookup = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToHashSet(
    [string[]]$originalMembers.Name, 
    [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

$currentMembers | 
    Where-Object {$originalMembersLookup.Contains($_.Name)}
```

Which will output the current members that were original members:

```
Name  Member_Number
----  -------------
Alice 4599
Jim   4567
```

---

### Update

As requested in the comments, If we want to check both `Name` and `Member_Number`, we can concatenate both strings to use for lookups:

```
$originalMembers = Import-Csv -Path .\Original_Members.csv
$currentMembers = Import-Csv -Path .\Current_Members.csv

$originalMembersLookup = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToHashSet(
    [string[]]($originalMembers | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $_.Name + $_.Member_Number
        }), 
    [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

$currentMembers | 
    Where-Object {$originalMembersLookup.Contains($_.Name + $_.Member_Number)}
```

Which will now only return:

```
Name Member_Number
---- -------------
Jim  4567
```